# Search for a sub-string using regular expression

Tags: regex

Have a use case where I have to process through several thousand doctor record notes and filter the ones that contain 'sick' in them but want to avoid cases where it may have a string such as 'not sick' or 'no sick'. 
**Sample Input :**

> ['individual looks sick', 'it is a great day', 'sick', 'sicker than
>   yesterday', 'not sick at all']

**Expected Output:**

> ['individual looks sick', 'sick', 'sicker than yesterday']

Comment: Can you add a sample of the input. Are the doctor a class/ array/ object. Also what is the expected output. Almost 100% sure this will be solved via ``filter`` and ``match``

Comment: I use this site all the time to create and test regex, https://regex101.com/

Comment: Are you asking for regular expressions? for java code? javascript?

Comment: Java != JavaScript. Which are you asking about?

Comment: Asking just for a regular expression here.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use below regex:

```
^.*?(?<!not\s|no\s)sick.*$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Nrsg4G/2

Test:

```
individual looks sick
it is a great day
sick
sicker than yesterday
not sick at all
no sick
```

Match :

```
individual looks sick 
sick
sicker than yesterday
```

Comment: Looks good. The first `?` doesn't make any difference though, does it?